# Apache windows local host working but ip is not working

Tags: apache, apache2, httpd.conf, htdocs

In my Apache server local host works but when i type the ip of the pc its not working... I have listen port configured on 78 and 5533. Localhost:78 and localhost:5533 works but not 127.0.0.1:78 and 127.0.0.1:5533 not working. Here is the httpd.conf

```
     enter co#
 # This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
 # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
 # See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2> for detailed information.
 # In particular, see 
 # <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html>
 # for a discussion of each configuration directive.
 #
 # Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
 # what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
 # consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
 #
 # Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
 # of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
 # server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
 # with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/foo.log"
 # with ServerRoot set to "C:/Apache2" will be interpreted by the
 # server as "C:/Apache2/logs/foo.log".
 #
 # NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
 # instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
 # If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which httpd.exe is located
 # will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
 # an explicit drive letter in absolute paths to avoid confusion.

 #
 # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
 # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
 #
 # Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
 # ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
 # at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
 # httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
 # ServerRoot "C:/Apache2"

 #
 # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
 # ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
 # directive.
 #
 # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
 # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
 #
 #Listen 12.34.56.78:80 Listen 78 Listen 5533

 #
 # Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
 #
 # To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
 # have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
 # directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
 # Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
 # to be loaded here.
 #
 # Example:
 # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
 # LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so LoadModule asis_module
 modules/mod_asis.so LoadModule auth_basic_module
 modules/mod_auth_basic.so
 #LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
 #LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
 #LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
 #LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
 #LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so LoadModule
 authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
 #LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
 #LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so LoadModule
 authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so LoadModule
 authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
 #LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so LoadModule
 autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
 #LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
 #LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
 #LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
 #LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
 #LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
 #LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
 #LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
 #LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
 #LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
 #LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
 #LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
 #LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
 #LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
 #LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
 #LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
 #LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
 #LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
 #LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
 #LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
 #LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
 #LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
 #LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
 #LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
 #LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
 #LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
 #LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
 #LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
 #LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
 #LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
 #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
 #LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
 #LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
 #LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
 #LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
 #LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
 #LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
 #LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
 #LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
 #LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

 <IfModule !mpm_netware_module> <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
 #
 # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
 # httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
 #
 # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
 # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
 # running httpd, as with most system services.
 # User daemon Group daemon

 </IfModule> </IfModule>

 # 'Main' server configuration
 #
 # The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
 # server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
 # <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
 # any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
 #
 # All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
 # in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
 # virtual host being defined.
 #

 #
 # ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
 # e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
 # as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
 # ServerAdmin root@h.com

 #
 # ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
 # This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
 # it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
 #
 # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
 #
 #ServerName localhost:80

 #
 # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
 # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
 # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
 # DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs"

 #
 # Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
 # to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
 # directory (and its subdirectories). 
 #
 # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
 # features.  
 # <Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all </Directory>

 #
 # Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
 # particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
 # you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
 # below.
 #

 #
 # This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
 # <Directory "C:/Apache2/htdocs">
     #
     # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
     # or any combination of:
     #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
     #
     # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
     # doesn't give it to you.
     #
     # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
     # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
     # for more information.
     #
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

     #
     # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
     # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
     #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
     #
     AllowOverride None

     #
     # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
     #
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all

 </Directory>

 #
 # DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
 # is requested.
 # <IfModule dir_module>
     DirectoryIndex index.php </IfModule>

 #
 # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
 # viewed by Web clients. 
 # <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
     Order allow,deny
     Deny from all
     Satisfy All </FilesMatch>

 #
 # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
 # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
 # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
 # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
 # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
 # ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

 #
 # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
 # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
 # alert, emerg.
 # LogLevel warn

 <IfModule log_config_module>
     #
     # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
     # a CustomLog directive (see below).
     #
     LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
     LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

     <IfModule logio_module>
       # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
       LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
     </IfModule>

     #
     # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
     # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
     # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
     # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
     # logged therein and *not* in this file.
     #
     # CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

     #
     # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
     # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
     #
     #CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined </IfModule>

 <IfModule alias_module>
     #
     # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
     # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
     # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
     # Example:
     # Redirect permanent /foo http://localhost/bar

     #
     # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
     # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
     # Example:
     # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
     #
     # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
     # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
     # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
     # the filesystem path.

     #
     # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
     # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
     # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
     # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
     # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
     # directives as to Alias.
     #
     ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Apache2/cgi-bin/"

 </IfModule>

 <IfModule cgid_module>
     #
     # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
     # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
     #
     #Scriptsock logs/cgisock </IfModule>

 #
 # "C:/Apache2/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
 # CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
 # <Directory "C:/Apache2/cgi-bin">
     AllowOverride None
     Options None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all </Directory>

 #
 # DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
 # if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
 # If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
 # a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
 # or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
 # keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
 # text.
 # DefaultType text/plain

 <IfModule mime_module>
     #
     # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
     # filename extension to MIME-type.
     #
     TypesConfig conf/mime.types

     #
     # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
     # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
     #
     #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
     #
     # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
     # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
     #
     #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
     #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
     #
     # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
     # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
     #
     AddType application/x-compress .Z
     AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

     #
     # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
     # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
     # or added with the Action directive (see below)
     #
     # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
     # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
     #
     #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

     # For type maps (negotiated resources):
     #AddHandler type-map var

     #
     # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
     #
     # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
     # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
     #
     #AddType text/html .shtml
     #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml </IfModule>

 #
 # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
 # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
 # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
 #
 #MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

 #
 # Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
 # 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
 #
 # Some examples:
 #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
 #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
 #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
 #ErrorDocument 402 http://localhost/subscription_info.html
 #

 #
 # MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
 # returning the entire resource, or one of the special
 # values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
 # Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
 #MaxRanges unlimited

 #
 # EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
 # memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
 # files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
 # be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
 # filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
 # broken on your system.
 #
 #EnableMMAP off
 #EnableSendfile off

 # Supplemental configuration
 #
 # The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
 # included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
 # the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
 # necessary.

 # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

 # Multi-language error messages
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

 # Fancy directory listings
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

 # Language settings
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

 # User home directories
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

 # Real-time info on requests and configuration Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

 # Virtual hosts
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

 # Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

 # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

 # Various default settings
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

 # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
 #Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
 #
 # Note: The following must must be present to support
 #       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
 #       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
 # <IfModule ssl_module> SSLRandomSeed startup builtin SSLRandomSeed connect builtin </IfModule>

 #
 # mod_expire modules configuration 
 # <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 # turn on the module for this directory ExpiresActive on

 # cache common graphics for 3 days ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 years" ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 years"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 years" ExpiresByType image/png
 "access plus 1 years"

 # cache CSS for 24 hours ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 years"

 # Javascript  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 years"

 # set the default to 24 hours ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 months" </IfModule>

 # End of mod_expire config


 alias /download "C:/apache2/dw/" <Directory "C:/Apache2/dw">
     AllowOverride None
     Options Indexes
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all </Directory>


 #BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL PHPIniDir "C:/PHP/" LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
 #END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL

 #
 # mod_expire modules configuration 
 # <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 # turn on the module for this directory ExpiresActive on

 # cache common graphics for 3 days ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 years" ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 years"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 years" ExpiresByType image/png
 "access plus 1 years"

 # cache CSS for 24 hours ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 years"

 # Javascript  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 years"

 # set the default to 24 hours ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 months" </IfModule>

 # End of mod_expire config

 # mod_deflate config start AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml

 SetOutputFilter DEFLATE SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI
 \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ \
     no-gzip dont-vary SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
     \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ \
     no-gzip dont-vary SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary

 BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html BrowserMatch
 ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip
 !gzip-only-text/html

 # ----------------- End of deflate conf ---------------------

 alias /download "C:/apache2/dw/" <Directory "C:/Apache2/dw">
     AllowOverride None
     Options Indexes
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all </Directory>

 <VirtualHost *:78>
     DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs"
     <Directory "C:/Apache2/htdocs">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride None
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>


     <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
         AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript application/javascript text/html text/plain text/xml
     </IfModule>


     <Location /vsc>
         Order Deny,Allow
         Deny From All
     </Location> </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:5533>
     DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/vsc"

     Alias /css "C:/Apache2/htdocs/css"   
     Alias /js "C:/Apache2/htdocs/js"
     Alias /images "C:/Apache2/htdocs/images"   

     <Directory "C:/Apache2/htdocs">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride None
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>

     <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
         AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript application/javascript text/html text/plain text/xml
     </IfModule>
     </VirtualHost> de here
```

Comment: Where are you Listen directives? Can't see them, there lies the key to solve the issue.

Comment: Here is the listen directive. # 
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 
Listen 78 
Listen 5533

Comment: That is all commented, so it has no effect! Where is the non commented Listen directive? If not, you should start adding one.